# tweepy.stream is giving 'None Type' object has no attribute 'on_exception' in streaming.py

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tweepy

I am using this function to read Tweets from Twitter, and I am getting an error on line 6 in `filter`:

```
def sendData (c_socket):
    authorization = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    authorization.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    twitter_stream = Stream(authorization, Twitter(c_socket))
    twitter_stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=["#"])
```

Comment: What kind of an error?

Comment: Can you please provide what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a full traceback it's difficult to determine the exact issue, but whatever `Twitter(c_socket)` is, it's likely returning `None` instead of a `StreamListener`.